# How to parse the objects and get the specific field in node.js

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore

I retrieved the object type data from the firestore and stored in a variable document

```
{ Invite1: { Amount: 25, PhoneNumber: 917995954482 },
  Invite2: { Amount: 25, PhoneNumber: 918179405940 },
  Invite3: { Amount: 25, PhoneNumber: 918179441493 },
  Invite4: { Amount: 25, PhoneNumber: 918309097608 } }
```

Now, I need to get the PhoneNumber from all the Invite.
After getting all the phone numbers into an array I need to check these Phone numbers already exists in database path like

```
/deyaPayUsers // collection
 {authid}    //document
     Name: abcd
     Phone Number: 987654321
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try this :)

```
var phoneNumbers = [];

var data = { Invite1: { Amount: 25, PhoneNumber: 917995954482 },
  Invite2: { Amount: 25, PhoneNumber: 918179405940 },
  Invite3: { Amount: 25, PhoneNumber: 918179441493 },
  Invite4: { Amount: 25, PhoneNumber: 918309097608 } }

for(var k  in data){
    phoneNumbers.push(data[k].PhoneNumber);
}
```

Comment: I need to query all these phone numbers with another path.  If I took the resultant in an array can I query whether this phone numbers are already exists in firestore

Comment: Sorry for that :( I am only familiar with real time database in Firebase

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var phoneNumbers = Object.keys(document).map(item => document[item].PhoneNumber);
```

Edited to take document as an object instead of array.

Comment: @Bleu you’re right, I must have assumed it was an array and overlooked the `{ }`!